# Getting OS version from Prometheus node_exporter

Tags: linux, prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

I have couple of Vms running CentOS. Preparing a dashboard in Grafana to monitor my all machines with Prometheus node_exporter. I need Exact OS version with decimal point. Like my centos versions are 7.6, 7.8, and 7.9. But from queries `node_os_info` and `node_os_version`, I am getting only `7`. Is there any way to get `7.8` and so on?

Comment: dont know if it helps but you can get kernel version from `node_uname_info`